# Ant jUnit WebDriver - file encoding

Tags: ant, junit

I am using spanish UTF-8 characters in my WebDriver test which works ok if ran from Eclipse, but if I try to run the same via Ant the test fails as it cannot find some elements with special characters. I figured out the encoding is messed up but I cannot seem to set up it properly. I tried the following to no avail

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" fork="yes">
    <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${bin}" />
            <fileset dir="${lib}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>

    <test name="com.yourcompany.selenium.MyTest" haltonfailure="no" todir="${report}/xml" outfile="TEST-result">
        <formatter type="xml" />
    </test>
</junit>
```

Tried also by adding the encoding value to command line, but the test still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit. The encoding was handled correctly by the junit task, the problem was at the compiling level as Ant seemed to compile using Cp1250 encoding. Adding encoding="UTF-8" to the compile task solved the problem.